# KDB Checking for matching values in an empty mixed list

Tags: kdb

I am trying to extract values from a column of type C and compare the value with various strings. A simple in works well as long as the column value is not null.

```
a: exec colName from select from tableName where date=yyyy.mm.dd
$[a in ("aa";"bb";"cc");show "Matched"; show "Not Matched"]
```

Problem is when a is an empty list of type 0h, then my if condition fails.

```
q)a: "aa"
q)$[a in ("aa";"bb";"cc");show "Matched"; show "Not Matched"]
 "Matched"
q)
q)a:()
q)type a
 0h
q)$[a in ("aa";"bb";"cc");show "Matched"; show "Not Matched"]
 'type
 [0]  $[a in ("aa";"bb";"cc");show "Matched"; show "Not Matched"]
       ^
q)
```

I have also tried the following which didn't work either

```
q)$[any a like/: ("aa";"bb";"cc");show "Matched";show "Not Matched"]
 'type
 [0]  $[any a like/: ("aa";"bb";"cc");show "Matched";show "Not Matched"]
     ^
q)
```

Ideally values in the list should be converted to string if present, but in this case there aren't any. How would one get around this?

Answer (score 1):

This worked

```
q)$[any a in ("aa";"bb";"cc");show "Matched";show "Not Matched"]
  "Not Matched"
q)
```

Comment: I would argue that your problem is that the "empty" version of string "aa" shouldn't be `()`, it should be `""`. So your process is not passing the correct null string. Your workaround is good, but seems like the issue is upstream